# In ASP.NET MVC, how can I have Listboxes to manage the content of two lists

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

In a website made in ASP MVC, I have been requested to build up a page that offers the functionality to manage the content of two lists of strings like [*****this*****.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8nMq.png)

The two listbox needs to be single-select, with a button to switch an item from one side to the other.

I'd like it to be client-sided, so that on submit of the form, the model binder can post the updated lists of strings to the controler.

Anyone know if such a control already exists, like those offered in jqueryUI. If not, any suggestions on how to acheive that result?

Thanks a lot folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [article](http://www.ryancramer.com/journal/entries/select_multiple/) that talks about usability issues and compares different approaches for multiselect inputs. This resource should help you.

Personally I like options SCROLLABLE CHECKBOXES and ASMSELECT

Comment: The article you submitted gave me some insights. The answer I was looking for was actually inside the article related resources: "Multi Select Transfer with jQuery" http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/easy-multi-select-transfer-with-jquery.html  

8 lines of javascript code and a dropdownlist. Simple and efficient! Thank you!

Comment: For future visitors, I will combine this client-sided solution with the server sided code provided in this link to bind with the controler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759493/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-data-binding.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options I was exploring just recently.

You can try this pure javascript version http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/picklist.shtml

Or I started building a JQuery plugin that you can use as a starting point
http://jsfiddle.net/stokedout/aySLN/4/

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.twinList = function (options) {

    var settings = $.extend({

        // Styling
        containerClass: 'twl-container',
        btnContainerClass: 'twl-btn-container',
        leftListClass: 'twl-list left',
        rightListClass: 'twl-list right',
        selectBtnClass: 'twl-btn select',
        selectAllBtnClass: 'twl-btn select-all',
        deselectBtnClass: 'twl-btn deselect',
        deselectAllBtnClass: 'twl-btn deselect-all',

        // Content
        selectBtnText: '>',
        selectAllBtnText: '>>',
        deselectBtnText: '<',
        deselectAllBtnText: '<<',

        // Config
        debug:true
    }, options);

    return this.each(function () {

        var originalList = $(this),
            originalOptions = originalList.find('option'),
            container,
            btnContainer,
            leftList,
            rightList,
            select,
            selectAll,
            deselect,
            deselectAll;

        var updateOriginalInput = function () {

            var rlOptions = rightList.find('option');

            originalOptions.prop('selected', false);

            for (var i = 0; i < originalOptions.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < rlOptions.length; j++) {
                    if (originalOptions[i].value === rlOptions[j].value) {
                        originalOptions[i].selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        container = $('<div/>', {
            'class': settings.containerClass
        });

        leftList = $('<select/>', {
            'class': settings.leftListClass,
            multiple: true
        });

        rightList = $('<select/>', {
            'class': settings.rightListClass,
            multiple: true
        });

        btnContainer = $('<div/>', {
            'class': settings.btnContainerClass
        });

        select = $('<a>', {
            text: settings.selectBtnText,
                'class': settings.selectBtnClass,
            href: '#',
            click: function (e) {
                leftList.find('option:selected').appendTo(rightList);
                updateOriginalInput();
            }
        });

        selectAll = $('<a>', {
            text: settings.selectAllBtnText,
                'class': settings.selectAllBtnClass,
            href: '#',
            click: function (e) {
                leftList.find('option').appendTo(rightList);
                originalOptions.prop('selected', true);
            }
        });

        deselect = $('<a>', {
            text: settings.deselectBtnText,
                'class': settings.deselectBtnClass,
            href: '#',
            click: function (e) {
                rightList.find('option:selected').appendTo(leftList);
                updateOriginalInput();
            }
        });

        deselectAll = $('<a>', {
            text: settings.deselectAllBtnText,
                'class': settings.deselectAllBtnClass,
            href: '#',
            click: function (e) {
                rightList.find('option').appendTo(leftList);
                originalOptions.prop('selected', false);
            }
        });

        leftList.append(originalOptions.clone());

        btnContainer.append(select)
            .append(selectAll)
            .append(deselect)
            .append(deselectAll);

        container.append(leftList)
            .append(btnContainer)
            .append(rightList);

        container.insertAfter(originalList);

        if (!settings.debug)
            originalList.hide();
    });

};

})(jQuery);

$('#someList').twinList();
```

To start off you just need to bind a @Html.DropDownListFor() with some data.

Comment: Thank you, I will probably use some ideas in there if my user requires more advanced functionalities with the control! I will upvote you when I get enough reputation to do so!

Comment: No problem, the scrollable checkbox solution from @Dmitry looked good ;-)